# SQL Server looking for missing records in one table where column may contain NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have two databases `Live` and `Dev`. The `Dev` database contains a number of records which need to be added to the live database, but the two databases share a number of records. There is a unique key on `MainspecialityCode`, `AppointmentType` and `ConsultantCode`. No record exists with all three being null but records exist where `AppointmentType` and `Consultantcode`

I tried the following:

```
SELECT [R_Dev].[ID]
      ,[R_Dev].[MainspecialityCode]
      ,[R_Dev].[Consultantcode]
      ,[R_Dev].[AppointmentType]
      ,[R_Dev].[GPCode]
      ,[R_Dev].[Process]
      ,[R_Dev].[Routing]
      ,[R_Dev].[CernerDocumentName]
      ,[R_Dev].[EmailAlert]
      ,[R_Dev].[ShowConsultant]
      ,[R_LIV].[MainspecialityCode]
      ,[R_LIV].[Consultantcode]
      ,[R_LIV].[AppointmentType]
FROM 
    [STG1DOCDB10].[CalypsoPrint_Live].[dbo].[Cerner_Routing] R_Dev
LEFT JOIN  
    [CalypsoPrint_Live].[dbo].[Cerner_Routing] R_LIV ON [R_LIV].[MainspecialityCode] = [R_Dev].[MainspecialityCode] 
                                                     AND [R_LIV].[Consultantcode] = [R_Dev].[Consultantcode] 
                                                     AND [R_LIV].[AppointmentType] = [R_Dev].AppointmentType
WHERE
    [R_LIV].[MainspecialityCode] IS NULL
    AND [R_LIV].[Consultantcode] IS NULL
    AND [R_LIV].[AppointmentType] IS NULL
```

However I am finding that records which are in both still appear in the results. So how can I do the comparison in the Where clause which only lists the records in dev that are not in live.

Comment: Why not `JOIN` on the `ID`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem are your `NULL` values which are failing the `LEFT JOIN`.  So, modify that to take them into account:

```
FROM [STG1DOCDB10].[CalypsoPrint_Live].[dbo].[Cerner_Routing] R_Dev LEFT JOIN
     [CalypsoPrint_Live].[dbo].[Cerner_Routing] R_LIV 
     ON [R_LIV].[MainspecialityCode] = [R_Dev].[MainspecialityCode] And
        ([R_LIV].[Consultantcode] = [R_Dev].[Consultantcode] OR
         [R_LIV].[Consultantcode] IS NULL AND [R_Dev].[Consultantcode] IS NULL
        ) AND
        ([R_LIV].[AppointmentType] = [R_Dev].AppointmentType OR
         [R_LIV].[AppointmentType] IS NULL AND [R_Dev].AppointmentType IS NULL
        )
```

Your `WHERE` clause only needs to check for `MainspecialityCode`.

Comment: Thanks tried that but still not coming back with the right values. It returns 303 rows when the only 75 extra rows.

Comment: what has helped me in past is ISNULL(MainspecialityCode,'') = ''

Comment: @PaulSChapman . . . Perhaps you have  multiple matches between the two tables.

Comment: @junketsu - that certainly seems to have got me closer, only 77 rows ( so 2 from what I expected , there should be no records which are empty in those fields )

Comment: Build on that further and put another condition where MainspecialityCode = 'NULL' or MainspecialityCode is NULL or ISNULL(MainspecialityCode,'') = ''